# SSRS Conditional Summing

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, sum

I have an SSRS report that displays several pages of rows.  In each row is a "TYPE" field.  In that TYPE field there is either an "M" for the value or a "P" for the value.  At the end of the report I want to summ up all the price values for the "P" TYPES.  I tried this but it prioduced an #Error:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!TYPE.Value = "P",Fields!EXT_QTY.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value ,0))
```

this summed all rows

```
=iif(Fields!PART_TYPE.Value = "P" ,  Sum(Fields!EXT_QTY.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value ),  0 )
```

I'm sure this is do-able.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Why CDbl is required in this scenario?

Comment: in OP's scenario `Sum(Fields!EXT_QTY.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value )` was producing numbers with double and/or decimal type and in SSRS when you perform SUM , it expects to SUM similar types and `0` is integer. It was failing because of that. So converting both true and false part of IIF statement to same data type resolves the error.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found the answer....

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!PART_TYPE.Value ="P",CDbl(Fields!EXT_QTY.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value), CDbl(0.0)))
```

Answer (score 16):

The `SUM` fails due to type comparison - you can't Sum values of different types, being the expression (probably a `Double`) with 0, an `Integer`. MikeTWebb's answer does explicit type conversion to get around this error. This is fine for this specific example, being a Sum, however this doesn't produce an accurate result if you want an average (being `Sum / Count`) of the values where the Type is P. That is because 0 is a value and would be included in the averaging calculation when you actually want those values excluded from the calculation.

Another option is to use `Nothing` instead of 0:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!TYPE.Value = "P", Fields!EXT_QTY.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value, Nothing))
```

This solves the type comparison error without needing explicit typecasting and is a better solution when you are using aggregations where whether the value exists or not is significant to the result, like `Average`.

Comment: This was perfect.  I definitely think that the use of Nothing is the way to go as a "rule of thumb" because of calculations like Average.

Comment: Yay! This was exactly what I needed. Still don't get who thought of 'Nothing' beeing a good keyword for null though.