# ssrs iif conditional sum based on dense rank

Tags: reporting-services, sum, expression, conditional-statements, aggregation

I looked at this thread already but get #Error
[SSRS Conditional Summing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727121/ssrs-conditional-summing)

Back Story:
I have a ssrs report to qa. Total calls value is going up based on orders value i.e. total calls value repeats if a sales person took 5 orders.
This should not be the case. Example:

left side is wrong right side is correct at employee level in grey.
abc | 500 | order-001 
not 
abc |500 | order-001
abc |500 | order-002
abc |500 | order-003

So i modified the SP to use Dense rank function.
Now within SSRS
At supervisor level I want to do a sum of total calls

```
=sum(IIF(Fields!Dense_Rank.Value=1 Or "NULL",Fields!TotalCalls.Value,0))
```

but this expression is evaluating to #Error at Supervisor level.

Finally, I wish to get a quick fix for this not re-invent the wheel or change the requirements.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Fields!Dense_Rank.Value refers to a column in your dataset called Dense_Rank (naming fields after t-sql functions is not generally advised, as this may lead to confusion), I think what you are trying to achieve is the following:

```
=sum(
IIF
 (
   (Fields!Dense_Rank.Value=1 Or Fields!Dense_Rank.Value Is Nothing),
   Fields!TotalCalls.Value,
   0
 )
)
```